# How to count percentage based on several condition mysql from different table

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sql-insert, create-table

I have 2 tables like this with sales.id_Location = location.id_location (this is not real data, just data dummy) on sales table, id_order are the history of transaction, createdAt are the date transaction happen, sale are the amount of the transaction (kg), id_Location are the location of the shipping which connected with id_location in location table, createdby are the buyer.

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(
    id_order VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    createdAt datetime NOT NULL,
    sale DECIMAL(14,2) NOT NULL,
    id_location varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    createdby varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_order,createdAt)
);

INSERT INTO sales (id_order, createdAt, sale, id_location, createdby)
VALUES(1,'2016-02-02',100, 1, 123),
      (2,'2017-03-02',150, 2, 233),
      (3,'2018-02-02',200, 3, 234),
      (4,'2016-03-03',150, 1, 123),
      (5,'2017-03-04',100, 2, 2334),
      (6,'2018-03-05',200,3, 234),
       (7,'2016-03-10',200, 1, 233),
      (8,'2017-02-01',150, 2, 124),
      (9,'2018-02-04',250, 3, 233),
      (10,'2018-02-05',300, 2, 124);

CREATE TABLE location
(
     id_location varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     location_city varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO location(id_location, location_city)
VALUES (1, 'Jakarta'),
 (2, 'Depok'),
 (3, 'Bekasi');

select * from sales;
select * from location;
```

This is the fiddle 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=eac3dc2845bfa425fbd576cc18c72609

In this case I used mysql version 5.7, I want to find out statistic of sales for each location with this condition

1. the sales are between '2016-02-01' until '2018-03-10'
2. the buyers (column `createdby`) are doing transaction before '2018-03-10' and at least doing transaction **again** between '2016-02-01' - '2018-03-10',

So if the buyers are just doing transaction one time, or doing transaction more than one time but there's no transaction at all in between '2016-02-01' until '2018-03-10' then the buyers are not counted and not included

Based on that condition and based on the data dummy, the expected results just like this:

```
+----------+----------+---------+----------------+--------------------+
| Location | sale(kg) | sale(%) | count id_order | count id_order (%) |
+----------+----------+---------+----------------+--------------------+
| Jakarta  |      450 |   26,48 |              3 |              33,33 |
| Depok    |      600 |   35,30 |              3 |              33,33 |
| Bekasi   |      650 |   38,22 |              3 |              33,33 |
| TOtal    |     1700 |     100 |              9 |                100 |
+----------+----------+---------+----------------+--------------------+
```

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(location.location_city, 'Total') AS `Location`, 
  SUM(sale) AS `sale(kg)`,
  SUM(sale) / (SELECT SUM(sale) FROM sales) * 100 AS `sale (%)`, 
  COUNT(id_order) AS `count(id_order)`,
  COUNT(id_order) / (SELECT COUNT(id_order) FROM sales) * 100 AS `count(id_order) (%)`
FROM sales, location
where sales.id_location = location.id_location
and createdAt <= '2018-03-04'
and EXISTS (select 1 from sales s2, location l2 where
sales.id_location = s2.id_location
and sales.id_location = l2.id_location and
createdAt >= '2016-02-01'
and createdAt <= '2018-03-04')
GROUP BY location WITH ROLLUP
having count(createdby) > 1;
```

This is the fiddle 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=eac3dc2845bfa425fbd576cc18c72609

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way ca. 1992. Come. Join us.

Comment: noted! thankyou sir

Comment: Unclear... Why you count sales for `createdby = 234`? he doesn't match to the condition (2) - he has only one sale at or before '2018-03-04'...

Comment: sorry my bad sir, please check my edit thankyou very much @Akina

Comment: Your edition alters nothing in the problem which I have said about. The desired result does not match to the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(location_city, 'Total') AS `Location`, 
       SUM(sale) AS `sale(kg)`,
       SUM(sale) / ANY_VALUE(totalsum) * 100 AS `sale (%)`, 
       COUNT(id_order) AS `count(id_order)`,
       COUNT(id_order) / ANY_VALUE(totalcount) * 100 AS `count(id_order) (%)`
FROM sales
NATURAL JOIN location
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT s1.createdby
               FROM sales s1
               GROUP BY s1.createdby
               HAVING SUM(s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2018-03-04')
                  AND SUM(s1.createdAt <= '2018-03-04') > 1 ) clients
JOIN ( SELECT SUM(sale) totalsum, 
              COUNT(id_order) totalcount 
       FROM sales ) totals
GROUP BY location_city WITH ROLLUP
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=903bf1a6933bb1a8150d57a6ff618b08) (see comments in the fiddle).

---

> the total on percent in sale and count id_order should be 100 because it's count overall statistic for the date range not for overall data on data dummy – Fachry Dzaky

If so these total values must be calculated separately. Test

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(location_city, 'Total') AS `Location`, 
       SUM(sale) AS `sale(kg)`,
       SUM(sale) / ANY_VALUE(totalsum) * 100 AS `sale (%)`, 
       COUNT(id_order) AS `count(id_order)`,
       COUNT(id_order) / ANY_VALUE(totalcount) * 100 AS `count(id_order) (%)`
FROM sales
NATURAL JOIN location
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT s1.createdby
               FROM sales s1
               GROUP BY s1.createdby
               HAVING SUM(s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2018-03-04')
                  AND SUM(s1.createdAt <= '2018-03-04') > 1 ) clients
JOIN ( SELECT SUM(sale) totalsum, 
              COUNT(id_order) totalcount 
       FROM sales
       NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT s1.createdby
                      FROM sales s1
                      GROUP BY s1.createdby
                      HAVING SUM(s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2018-03-04')
                         AND SUM(s1.createdAt <= '2018-03-04') > 1 ) clients ) totals
GROUP BY location_city WITH ROLLUP
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a9fe484097a9e1563ba9147c4c34a670)

Comment: the total on percent in sale and count id_order should be 100 because it's count overall statistic for the date range not for overall data on data dummy

Comment: thankyou very much sir, have a nice day, hope you healthy as always

Comment: one more time sir, based on the queries from you, you dont put sales.id_location = location.id_location, is it because you put natural join?

Comment: @FachryDzaky Yes. `NATURAL JOIN` joins by ALL fields which have the same name (bounty - only one copy of a field is placed into output, not two). If such fields have different datatypes then datatype of the most former table is used.

Comment: sorry sir my bad, i forgot to add some field, its order_status_id, so if the order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8) then the transactioin are approved, so in this case, the query are also count in just approved transaction, which part i should add where order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8) ? this is the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6ec1b95b197cfe0069b90c58e9891fbe

Comment: @FachryDzaky Everywhere where the table is used in FROM. 4 copies of `sales` table == 4 `WHERE` conditions. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=347c885776773b5d39f095116c67c6c4).

Comment: sir this is the last, can you used another join like inner join or left join, because in my real case the 2 tables are have 2 same coloumn but only 1 coloumn are related, the other are not

Comment: @FachryDzaky Replace each `table_a NATURAL JOIN table_b` with `table_a INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.field_a=table_b.field_b` with accuracy.

Comment: please take a look at this, i just edited the natural join into inner join but the expected results was different https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=62b6328e394b3b74e453906f1fa4c2a7

Comment: @FachryDzaky [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b22217bc34e3fb40c41cbaf065ca7659).